# Java Record - Tests - Modify Fields

Tags: java, testing, reflection, java-record

I have a framework used exclusively for testing that sets fields at runtime. The purpose is to set up test cases. Looking forward to upgrading to Java 14+ records I am noticing that existing utilities such as `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` and `PropertyAccessorFactory.forDirectFieldAccess` which work on normal private final fields, do not work for record fields.

Is this a limitation of the JVM, or is a limitation of these utilities?

Comment: It's a limitation of these utilities. Record fields are final, that means that they can not be modified after they have been set. If you need a record with different values, create a new record.

Answer (score 5):

Since modifying the `private final` fields of a `record` is intentionally unsupported, it’s not a limitation of the JVM or Java execution environment, so relying on the ability to modify such fields is a limitation of these utilities.

The [documentation of `setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) says:

> This method cannot be used to enable *write* access to a *non-modifiable* final field. The following fields are non-modifiable:
>
> - static final fields declared in any class or interface
> - final fields declared in a hidden class
> - final fields declared in a record

The original intent of supporting to write a `final` instance field via access override, was to allow fixing the object state after cloning or deserializing. Neither is necessary for a `record`.

- Deserializing a `record` instance will invoke its constructor, so the constructor can apply all necessary validation and fixes before the final fields are assigned.
- Creating a shallow clone of a `record` has no point at all. For all other copying purposes, you can read all of its components, as each field has a corresponding accessor method, adapt them, and pass the adapted values to the always existing canonical constructor.

Comment: Please clarify. Answer states "is intentionally not supported", and also "it's not a limitation of the JVM or Java execution environment". These statements seem contradictory.

Comment: A limitation would be a missing feature, but here, the environment works exactly as intended. You can be sure that changing `record` fields after construction will never be supported.

Comment: I was using limitation in the sense of a limitation imposed by the JVM. Thanks for the clarification.