# SecurityManager deprecation and reflection with suppressAccessChecks

Tags: java-module, java-security-manager, java-19

I'm an university lecturer and I'm revising my lecture on Java reflection.
Other years when teaching about the horrors of suppressAccessChecks I was showing
that you could set up a SecurityManager and do something like

```
    if ("suppressAccessChecks".equals(p.getName())){
      StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
      if(.. st ..) { throw new SecurityException(); }
    }
```

In this way you can allow for whitelisted deserializers only to call suppressAccessChecks.
However, now they are deprecating the SecurityManager.
I think the new module system is supposed to help here, but I'm failing to find resources explaining how to support the idea of the whitelisted deserializers above.

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Java modules, [`setAccessible` is already restricted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)), even without a security manager:

> This method may be used by a caller in class `C` to enable access to a [`member`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) of [`declaring class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#getDeclaringClass()) `D` if any of the following hold:
>
> - `C` and `D` are in the same module.
> - The member is `public` and `D` is `public` in a package that the module containing `D` [`exports`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#isExported(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) to at least the module containing `C`.
> - The member is `protected static`, `D` is `public` in a package that the module containing `D` exports to at least the module containing `C`, and `C` is a subclass of `D`.
> - `D` is in a package that the module containing `D` [`opens`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#isOpen(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) to at least the module containing `C`. All packages in unnamed and open modules are open to all modules and so this method always succeeds when `D` is in an unnamed or open module.

If we assume a typical scenario of a module M using a persistence service in module P and the members are not accessible anyway, only the last bullet applies; `M` must *open* the package(s) to `P` to enable the access override.

This can be done via a [qualified `opens` directive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.2)

```java
module M {
  opens aPackage.needing.persistence to P;
}
```

This way, only the explicitly specified module(s), i.e. `P`, can use `setAccessible` for members of types in `aPackage.needing.persistence`.

In case of the HotSpot JVM, there’s the option `--add-opens` allowing to add qualified `opens` relationships at startup, in addition to declared ones, but there is no option for a module of an already running application to create such a relationship at runtime to gain additional access rights itself (unless the security is already subverted). It’s imaginable that other environments do not even support such a startup option.

---

It’s worth mentioning that there are still some new restrictions which can’t be circumvented this way. As also mentioned in [`setAccessible`’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)):

> This method cannot be used to enable [*write*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) access to a *non-modifiable* final field. The following fields are non-modifiable:
>
> - static final fields declared in any class or interface
> - final fields declared in a [hidden class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isHidden())
> - final fields declared in a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isRecord())

<sup>See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71051688/2711488)</sup>

In other words, in case of a `record` type, the persistence service still must use the constructor to deserialize an instance, even when suppressing access checks.

Comment: So, in a single module application we can not restrict setAccessible any more?
How does it work with dynamic loading of classes, how do I programmatically load a class in a separate module?

Comment: Within a single module, there is no restriction. It’s assumed that there is enough trust between the classes of a single module. It would be weird, if a class can allow another module access to its own module’s classes, but these classes wouldn’t trust each other. When you want to add a class to another module dynamically, are you talking about an existing module or about even creating the module dynamically?

Comment: It would be interesting to create a module dynamically... may be I should ask another question about it

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a new question.